# How to split messy string to letters and numbers using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have these two strings:

```
x ='plasma_glucose_concentration183.0000'
y = 'Participants20-30'
```

And want to split the strings as follow:

```
x: ['plasma_glucose_concentration', '183.0000']
y: ['Participants, 20-30']
```

I created this function, but only first string is split correctly:

```
def split_string(x):
    res = re.findall(r"(\w+?)(\d*\.\d+|\d+)", x)
    return res
```

When I split the second string I get:

```
  [('Participants', '20'), ('3', '0')]
```

Is there any regex solution for this? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re

x = ['plasma_glucose_concentration183.0000', 'Participants20-30','2_hour_serum_insulin543.0000']
for s in x:
    print(re.split(r'(?<=[^\W\d_])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[^\W\d_])', s))

# => ['plasma_glucose_concentration', '183.0000']
#    ['Participants', '20-30']
#    ['2_hour_serum_insulin', '543.0000']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eOWFkm/3) and the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/8RaBxd).

The `(?<=[^\W\d_])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[^\W\d_])` regex splits a string between a letter and a digit or between a digit and a letter.

Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['plasma_glucose_concentration183.0000','Participants20-30','2_hour_serum_insulin543.0000']})
>>> df['text'].str.split(r'(?<=[^\W\d_])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[^\W\d_])')
0    [plasma_glucose_concentration, 183.0000]
1                       [Participants, 20-30]
2            [2_hour_serum_insulin, 543.0000]
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, and what if the string is following:  `'2_hour_serum_insulin543.0000'` ?

Comment: @madmax80 No problem, [it works](https://regex101.com/r/eOWFkm/2).

Comment: Actually, I would like to get `['2_hour_serum_insulin', '543.0000'] ` instead of `['2', '_hour_serum_insulin', '543.0000']`

Comment: Great, do you know why Im getting  `ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.` with your pattern? Im using jupyter notebook and `pandas==1.1.4` and `Python 3.8.5`

Comment: @madmax80 Beginning with Python 3.7, `re.split` allows empty pattern match. I tested the solution in Python 3.7.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the Python version and now it works.